# Comparing the distribution fits of a bivariate and a univariate model

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood, model-selection, conditional-probability

Suppose I've done an experiment and I have a distribution of observations $x$ that vary between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

Now suppose each $x$ is associated with a second observation $y$ that may or may not influence the value $x$ takes.  This second variable $y$ also varies between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

I have two models for how $x$ should be distributed.  One model ignores $y$; the other does not.  I want to see which fits my data better.

To make this concrete, let's say that Model 1 is a von Mises PDF.  For each $x$ value, it returns a probability density.  Its shape is determined by a single parameter $\kappa$, the concentration.  So we have Model 1 = $VM(x; \kappa)$.

Let's say Model 2 has its basis in the von Mises PDF for $x$, but is more complicated.  For each $x$, the mean of the von Mises is biased in the direction of the corresponding $y$. The conditional density of $x$ given $y$ here is $VM(x|y; g(y), \kappa)$, where $\mu=g(y)$ is the mean of the von Mises on each trial. ($g$ is some function of y with some number of parameters -- say two parameters $h$ and $w$.)

Finally, say I want to compare the models using the AIC.  Maximizing the likelihood of Model 1 is straightforward. I simply find the $\kappa$ that maximizes the summed probabilities of my $x$ values. For Model 2, it's not as clear to me what my likelihood function should be.

My question is, what should my likelihood function be for Model 2?  It's clear I need to find the $\kappa$, $h$, and $w$ that maximize the likelihood, but . . . is the likelihood function the joint density for all $x$ and $y$?  The marginal density of $x$?  Something else?  Why?  Which model parameters would I count in the computation of the AIC? Is it important to note that my data sample the space of all possible $x$ and $y$ pairs less thoroughly than the data sample the space of all possible $x$ values (ignoring $y$)?

Comment: The description of Model 2 is so vague that it may be difficult to give good advice.  It even appears it involves more parameters than you have observations, suggesting it might not even be identifiable.  Could you present Model 2 in a more explicit manner?

Comment: @whuber sure, happy to help.  unless you're really struggling with reading comprehension, you must have meant to ask me to give you an example for $g$.  let's say $g$ is a Gabor function with a height ($h$) and a width ($w$) parameter.  for each $y$, given $h$ and $w$, it computes a mean bias $\mu$ for the von Mises.

Comment: I flagged your earlier comment and so it was automatically deleted.  The basis for the flag is explained at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice .  I appreciate that you removed the gratuitous insult.  I am, however, still struggling with comprehending this question and therefore--in my role as moderator--believe that others (if any are interested) might have similar difficulties determining what Model 2 really is.  But you don't have to take my suggestions, which are motivated only to help you get good answers: you're welcome to leave your question unedited and trust to luck.

Comment: @whuber fair enough, i was just getting you back for blaming me for some other author's analysis mistake two years ago.  i can definitely rephrase my description of Model 2, but it's not clear to me where you're getting stuck.  $y$ gets fed to $g$, $g$ spits out $\mu$, and then the von Mises gives a probability for $x$ given $\mu$.  the fixed parameters are $\kappa$ (for the von Mises) and $h$ and $w$, for $g$.  $x$ and $y$ are observations -- one for each trial.  $y$ is an IV, $x$ a DV.  (they are observations in a loose sense -- they are trial-by-trial variables that are input to the model.)

Comment: I'll confess that I had drafted an answer to your question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199866/kurtosis-for-circular-data and was also looking forward with interest to this one.  However, seeing no reward in being insulted continually, I have abandoned those efforts and see no need to return to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In attempting this comparison, the marginal density for $x$ would be the likelihood function to use for Model 2.  Like the likelihood function for Model 1, it computes a single probability for each $x$ value.  However, for Model 2, the marginal density is

\begin{align}
p(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\pi_{-\pi}VM\bigg(x|y; g(y; h, w), \kappa\bigg)dy,
\end{align}

assuming $y$ is drawn from a uniform distribution.  This is a bit tricky, if not impossible, to compute analytically.

What you can do is approximate it numerically using one of the methods described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1712292/219075).

Another option is to fix $y$ in your experimental design at a value expected to reveal differences between Model 1 and Model 2.  (This is possible only if $y$ is an independent variable.)  In such a design, the differences between the models would reduce to the absence/presence of a constant bias in the mean of the von Mises.

As a final note, characterizing $y$'s influence on $x$ doesn't require fitting a PDF to observations.  This influence could be characterized in many different ways, with other sorts of fits to other representations of the data.